# Sail boat from Santiago Chile to Tahiti

Tags: transportation, chile, sailing, pacific-ocean, tahiti

I am trying to find out how easy it is to catch a sail boat from Santiago, Chile to Tahiti or beyond. I am a skilled (older female!) coastal sailor but would like to crew on a Transpacific journey. Any, and all, info will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 7):

Your best bet is on a site like [findacrew](http://www.findacrew.net/).  I've had a friend do it this way - she overlanded from London to NZ, and used findacrew for the ocean parts inbetween.

Generally there are categories of sailors on it - from beginner to expert, and as you've mentioned, you're already skilled.  This will give you a considerable advantage.

Thinking about it, another site I'd recommend is [Explorers Connect](http://www.explorersconnect.com/). While I've not used them to get a gig, I get their newsletter - and have for years, and regularly see people finding each other on there to form a crew/expedition/mission for all sorts of amazing adventures.  I actually think that may be your best bet for something like this!

Please do let us know how it goes!